# how to create a folder in s3 bucket by using python boto3 code for with conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

In S3 bucket the folder_name was saved by company_id's. I am passing the company_id based on company_id in s3 bucket have to check that company_id or not .

- if the company_id is not in S3 bucket have to create a new folder and upload a files
- else company_id is in s3 bucket then the file should be insert in that folder.

But I don't know how to check this condition, I have a upload file code but have to check this condition. Here is my code:

```
class AddImageUpload(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        try:
            myfile = request.FILES['fileUpload']
            myfolder = request.Folders['company_id']
            user_id=request.data.get("ip_user_id")
            company_id = request.data.get("ip_company_id")
            now = datetime.datetime.now()
            timestamp =  int(datetime.datetime.timestamp(now))
            print("timestamp =", timestamp)
            fsize = myfile.files[0].size;
            # // Size
            # returned in bytes.
            fsizekb = fsize / 1024;
            # Convert to KBytes
            # #
            # if (fsizekb > 100):
            #    {
            #      alert('Your File size is more than specific size; Size of your file'+fsizekb.toFixed(2)+'KB')
            #       return HttpResponse ('false')
            #    }
            #     {
            #       var
            #        objFSO = new
            #        ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
            #      var
            #         e = objFSO.getFile(fileInput.value);
            #     var
            #     fileSize = e.size;
            #     var
            #     fsizekb = filesize / 1024;
            #
            #     if (fsizekb > 100){
            #     alert("Your File size is more than specific size; Size of your file.(CC)"+fsizekb.toFixed(2)+" KB");
            #     return false;
            #     }
            #     }
            #     return true;

            res = upload_to_aws(myfile,user_id,myfile.name,timestamp,company_id,myfolder)
            if res == True:
                result = settings.S3BucketLink + myfile.name
                returnobj = {
                    'isuploaded': res,
                    'imageurl': result
                }
                return HttpResponse(json.dumps(returnobj))
            else:
                returnobj = {
                    'isuploaded': res,
                    'imageurl': ""
                }
                return HttpResponse(json.dumps(returnobj))
        except Exception as err:
            http_err = traceback.format_exc()
            self.error_logger.error(http_err)
            return HttpResponse(err)
        finally:
            execute_function().close_db_connection()


def upload_to_aws(filedata,user_id,filename,timestamp,company_id,myfolder):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=settings.S3_BUCKET_BUCKET_AccessKeyId,
                      aws_secret_access_key=settings.S3_BUCKET_BUCKET_SecretAccessKey)

    try:
        curntfilename = filedata.name+str(timestamp)
        data = s3.upload_fileobj(filedata, settings.S3_BUCKET_BUCKET_NAME, '%s/%s' % (settings.users, filename))
        uploadprofile(user_id,curntfilename,company_id,myfolder)
        print("Upload Successful")
        return True
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("The file was not found")
        return False
    except NoCredentialsError:
        print("Credentials not available")
        return False

def uploadprofile(user_id,curntfilename,company_id):
            try:
                company_id = company_id
                execute_function.get_connection_by_company(company_id)
                params = {
                    'ip_profile_name': curntfilename,
                    'ip_user_id':user_id
                }
                result = execute_function.put(params, db_functions.fn_ins_upd_user_profile)
                return HttpResponse(result)
            except Exception as err:
                http_err = traceback.format_exc()
                print(http_err)
                return HttpResponse(http_err, status=500)
            finally:
                execute_function().close_db_connection()
```

Answer (score 4):

Amazon S3 does not actually use folders. Instead, the `Key` (filename) of an object includes the **full path** of the object.

This means that **you can upload files to a folder even if the folder does not exist!** The folder will 'appear' in Amazon S3 automatically. Later, if you delete all files in the 'folder', then the folder will disappear (because it never actually existed).

While you can make 'folders' via the Amazon S3 management console, that actually creates a zero-length object that has the same name as the folder. This forces the folder to appear in the user interface, but does not actually create a 'folder' (since folders do not exist).

**Bottom line:** Simply pretend that your desired folder exists and feel free to upload to it. It will then 'appear'. There is no need to create a folder in an Amazon S3 bucket.

Answer (score 1):

S3 is an key based Object Store, the folders are really just a convenience for prefix to the key.

In order to know if a 'folder' exists, what you really are asking is there any key in the bucket with the 'folder' as the prefix

```
import boto3

resp = boto3.client('s3').list_objects_v2(
  Bucket=bucket,
  Prefix=prefix,
  MaxKeys=1
)

if resp['Contents']:
  return f'prefix {prefix} exists'
```

The evalualion of `resp['Contents']` will return *True* if the prefix exists.

refer to https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2 for more on the response and request options